# Microsoft Graph GetByIds support for query params ($select, $filter), or include additional properties in GetMemberGroups

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

*GetMemberGroups* only returns the "id" properties of the groups, afaik there is no way to include other additional properties (my guess it's because it only searches in some kind of index rather than actually traversing all nodes in the hierarchy, which makes sense when it needs to be transitive)

*DirectoryObjects.GetByIds* comes handy once I have the ids from GetMemberGroups, but this one returns all default properties. If I specify any $filter for example if I know that I don't need groups with certain prefix in displayName, or a $select because I know I will only need certain properties, any of these query parameters are ignored. No error thrown, just ignored, and all objects are returned with all parameters.

```
// this works (max 2046 results)
var groupIDs = await client.Users[userid].GetMemberGroups(false).Request().PostAsync()

// something like Expand or Include would be handy
// even if it is done separately in AD, at least we would save the roundtrip
client.Users[userid].GetMemberGroups(false).Request().Include("prop1,prop2").PostAsync()

// this works nicely with pagination, but both Select and Filter are ignored
var res = await client.DirectoryObjects.GetByIds(groupIDs.ToList(), new[] { "group" })
.Request().Select("id,displayName").Filter("startswith(displayName,'prefix')").PostAsync()
```

This scenario makes more sense when you are dealing with large result sets (), and you cannot cache values for too long, in these cases it can waste more bandwith than it should.

Is there any other option to achieve similar results? Or any hints on whether it is possible at all to support this, is anything similar on the roadmap?
Maybe @Dan Kershaw knows more, but if meanwhile I'm missing an already existing solution, would be nice to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a new feature request - to filter and select on a function or action in Microsoft Graph.  We don't have this today.  The only option currently available to you is to get the full set back, and do client side filtering/selection.

Can you create a [user voice request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis) for this new capability please

Hope this helps,